# Homebrew libiconv error

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, libiconv

i ran this following code

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
.................................................

$ brew doctor

Warning: /usr/local/include isn't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably chown /usr/local/include

Warning: /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig isn't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed by
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to write a file to this directory, the
install will fail during the link step.

You should probably chown /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

Warning: Some directories in /usr/local/share/locale aren't writable.
This can happen if you "sudo make install" software that isn't managed
by Homebrew. If a brew tries to add locale information to one of these
directories, then the install will fail during the link step.
You should probably chown them:

/usr/local/share/locale
/usr/local/share/locale/af
/usr/local/share/locale/af/LC_MESSAGES
.....
.......

Warning: gettext files detected at a system prefix
These files can cause compilation and link failures, especially if they
are compiled with improper architectures. Consider removing these files:
/usr/local/lib/libgettextlib.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libintl.dylib
/usr/local/include/libintl.h

Warning: libiconv files detected at a system prefix other than /usr
Homebrew doesn't provide a libiconv formula, and expects to link against
the system version in /usr. libiconv in other prefixes can cause
compile or link failure, especially if compiled with improper
architectures. OS X itself never installs anything to /usr/local so
it was either installed by a user or some other third party software.

tl;dr: delete these files:
/usr/local/lib/libiconv.dylib
/usr/local/include/iconv.h

Warning: You have MacPorts or Fink installed:
/opt/local/bin/port

This can cause trouble. You don't have to uninstall them, but you may want to
temporarily move them out of the way, e.g.

sudo mv /opt/local ~/macports

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
/usr/local/lib/libasprintf.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libcharset.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libcunit.1.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgettextlib-0.18.3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgettextpo.0.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libgettextsrc-0.18.3.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libjansson.4.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.7.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.0.dylib

Warning: Unbrewed .la files were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .la files:
/usr/local/lib/libasprintf.la
/usr/local/lib/libcharset.la
/usr/local/lib/libcunit.la
/usr/local/lib/libgettextlib.la
/usr/local/lib/libgettextpo.la
/usr/local/lib/libgettextsrc.la
/usr/local/lib/libiconv.la
/usr/local/lib/libintl.la
/usr/local/lib/libjansson.la
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.la
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.la

Warning: Unbrewed .pc files were found in /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected .pc files:
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/cunit.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/jansson.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/libiconv.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc

Warning: Unbrewed static libraries were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae, and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected static libraries:
/usr/local/lib/libasprintf.a
/usr/local/lib/libcharset.a
/usr/local/lib/libcunit.a
/usr/local/lib/libgettextpo.a
/usr/local/lib/libintl.a
/usr/local/lib/libjansson.a
/usr/local/lib/libltdl.a
/usr/local/lib/libsqlite3.a

Warning: You have unlinked kegs in your Cellar
Leaving kegs unlinked can lead to build-trouble and cause brews that depend on
those kegs to fail to run properly once built. Run brew link on these:

cunit
.........................................................
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

If i give "brew link libiconv" the following error is 
Warning: libiconv is keg-only and must be linked with --force
Note that doing so can interfere with building software.

Can you tell me how to resolve the libiconv missing error. I installed both Manually and via brew. But still get same following error.

still i getting error when i configure the gcc compile codes

```
...........
checking for libiconv_open in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open in -lc... no
checking for iconv_open in -liconv... no
configure: error: Could not find libiconv. Please install libiconv and libiconv-devel
```

Please help me to resolve this. i still break this error upto 2 days. I'm waiting your replies

Answer (score 2):

Wow! Lots of stuff to fix, there!

Where it says "You should probably chown /usr/local/include", it means you should run:

```
chown -R `whoami` /usr/local/include
```

(Same applies for all of the other messages like that.)

It looks like you have a lot of junk in /usr/local, though. I'd maybe move it somewhere else (like, /usr/local-broken) and then reinstall homebrew. You might get away with running

```
make uninstall
```

from whereever you installed libiconv from.

Once you've got all the brew doctor warnings resolved, I'd say something like

```
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/lib CPPFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/libiconv/include brew install whatever
```

might work for you! This way you're compiling with the libiconv files that homebrew built for you.

Good luck!